# Ruby on rails: XSS prevention: how do I prevent null from being passed as data to my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internet-explorer, xss

While non-IE browsers can handle the null character fine, IE just gives up on life when it encounters a null character. It just stops rendering the page.

I figure, since null will never be a legit piece of text in my app, I could block or strip it out of queries sent to the database.

How would I do this / what is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do this kind of cleansing when the data is submitted instead of during presentation (on-the-way-in vs. on-the-way-out), but either way the code to strip null characters is the same: `some_string.gsub(/\000/,"")` ... which merely strips null characters out of the offending string.

Comment: is there a way to do that globally over the whole app?

Comment: I don't know if its the *best* way, but the first thought that comes to mind for a global solution is to have a before_filter in your ApplicationController that iterates through params and applies that regex to every value.

Comment: yup, I just thought of that, actually. now.. implementation!